# define a "trick" standard ML function without specifying explicit type

Tags: type-inference, sml

This is an exercise from the standard ML tutorial seen here: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/stg/NOTES/node42.html

I am not taking a class so there is no cheating going on here. But I can't figure out how to do this. Can someone help?

The function `fn x => fn y => x` has type `'a -> ('b -> 'a)`. Without giving an explicit type constraint, define a function with type `'a -> ('a -> 'a)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint 1: You have to find an expression that has 2 or more subexpressions but requires them to have the same type.

Hint 2: Lists or conditionals are good contenders.

Hint 3: Of course, the subexpressions you put in there are the two arguments.

Hint 4: You don't need to use the result of this expression.

Comment: Got it while driving to home. I really enjoy this tutorial!

    > val idt = fn x => fn y => hd(x :: y :: nil);
    val idt = fn : 'a -> 'a -> 'a

Comment: And thank you Andreas for not answering my question:) I would be hitting my head against wall when I see the answer.